# Non recursive lambda evaluator that "magically" optimizes tail recursion

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, tail-recursion, lambda-calculus

I think pasting my main method `GetTermValue` plus the `StackFrame` class and a couple of helper methods (`Return` and `Replace`) should be all I need to keep it concise, but first a few notes about the code:

An `ILambdaValue` represents a value that is basically the result of evaluating an `ILambdaTerm`, which represents a parsed lambda term.

The `AbstractionValue` class is an `ILambdaFunction` (which in turn is an `ILambdaValue`) that contains an `IAbstractionTerm` (which is an `ILambdaTerm`) called `AbstractionTerm` that holds the parsed abstraction term, and an `IScope<ILambdaValue>` called `Scope` which represents the environment in which the abstraction value was created.

An `IScope` is just a string-key dictionary. `InnerScope` is an `IScope` that simulates lambda substitution by taking a parent scope and a dictionary and overwriting the parent scope with the values in the dictionary.

```
public class StackFrame
{
    public ILambdaTerm Term;
    public IScope<ILambdaValue> Scope;
    public List<ILambdaValue> Results = new List<ILambdaValue>();

    public StackFrame() { }

    public StackFrame(ILambdaTerm term, IScope<ILambdaValue> scope)
    {
        Term = term;
        Scope = scope;
    }
}

private static void Return(Stack<StackFrame> stack, ILambdaValue result)
{
    stack.Pop();
    stack.Peek().Results.Add(result);
}

private static void Replace(Stack<StackFrame> stack, StackFrame stackFrame)
{
    stack.Pop();
    stack.Push(stackFrame);
}

public static ILambdaValue GetTermValue(ILambdaTerm _term, IScope<ILambdaValue> _scope)
{
    Stack<StackFrame> stack = new Stack<StackFrame>();

    stack.Push(new StackFrame());
    stack.Push(new StackFrame(_term, _scope));

    while (stack.Count > 1)
    {
        var stackFrame = stack.Peek();

        switch (stackFrame.Term.TermKind)
        {
            case LambdaTermType.String:
                Return(stack, new StringValue(((ILiteralTerm<string>)stackFrame.Term).Value));
                break;
            case LambdaTermType.Number:
                Return(stack, new NumberValue(((ILiteralTerm<double>)stackFrame.Term).Value));
                break;
            case LambdaTermType.Boolean:
                Return(stack, new BooleanValue(((ILiteralTerm<bool>)stackFrame.Term).Value));
                break;
            case LambdaTermType.Variable:
                Return(stack, stackFrame.Scope[((IVariableTerm)stackFrame.Term).Name]);
                break;
            case LambdaTermType.Application:
                {
                    var application = (IApplicationTerm)stackFrame.Term;

                    if (stackFrame.Results.Count == 0)
                    {
                        stack.Push(new StackFrame(application.Function, stackFrame.Scope));
                    }
                    else if (stackFrame.Results.Count <= application.Arguments.Length)
                    {
                        stack.Push(new StackFrame(application.Arguments[stackFrame.Results.Count - 1], stackFrame.Scope));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var function = (ILambdaFunction)stackFrame.Results[0];
                        var argList = stackFrame.Results.Skip(1).ToList();

                        if (function is AbstractionValue) // If the function is a lambda-defined abstraction (see next `case`):
                        {
                            var abstraction = (AbstractionValue)function;
                            var substitutions = abstraction.AbstractionTerm.Parameters.Select((Param, Index) => new { Param, Index }).ToDictionary(ai => ai.Param.Name, ai => argList[ai.Index]);
                            InnerScope<ILambdaValue> innerScope = new InnerScope<ILambdaValue>(abstraction.Scope, substitutions);
                            Replace(stack, new StackFrame(abstraction.AbstractionTerm.Body, innerScope));
                        }
                        else // If the function is a built-in function so there's no abstraction:
                        {
                            Return(stack, function.ApplyTo(argList));
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case LambdaTermType.Abstraction:
                Return(stack, new AbstractionValue((IAbstractionTerm)stackFrame.Term, stackFrame.Scope));
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    return stack.Peek().Results[0];
}
```

What surprised me is that the code seems to "optimize" tail recursion. I've tested it with the typical tail recursive factorial function (note that, while not included in the code above, in my version of lambda calculus you can let-define global recursive functions such as `let overflow = \x.(overflow x)` (which actually happens not to overflow if evaluated with the code above)) and with a few other tail recursive functions and the stack didn't grow any bigger than some fixed value no matter how deep the recursion was. But I'm not 100% sure this wasn't just luck and perhaps it'd fail in some other cases. I wrote this kind of (not recursive) evaluator hoping I'd eventually figure out how to implement tail recursion optimization (just the word "optimization" makes it sound like so much trouble), but apparently I already did.

If it really optimizes tail recursion, I believe it may be because of the call to `Replace` at the end of the `if (function is AbstractionValue)` block. Apparently the stack won't grow as long as the recursion path doesn't include any function parameter. Which seems like the negative definition of tail recursion (I usually understand tail recursion as calling the recursive function as the last step, but since this is lambda calculus and there are no steps, this would be equivalent to not calling it in an application parameter).

So my questions are, is this code a correct lambda evaluation algorithm? And also, does it really "optimizes" tail recursion as it seems to?

Comment: You are talking about your intern stack right? It's not easy to read (not your fault - maybe F# next time ;) ) but I think this will not grow much because you lift most of the recursive stuff into your "closures" (the substitutions ;) ) - you can test this using a memory profiler and looking for this stuff - but interesting stuff - maybe put it on github or something so we can have a real look?

Comment: @CarstenKönig Actually, is not storing the data into any closure. Is basically replacing the abstraction with it's body, so nothing builds up.